# Javascript 404 not found, but PHP and CSS loading

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, permissions, javascript

I've got a Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS cloud server running the default LAMP stack.

My website is serving my PHP pages, the images and CSS to go with them, and most of my JS is loading, but there is a particular folder that is not loading the javascript files.

If I visit my site, *site.com/javascript/search.js* then I get a 404. If I visit *site.com/includes/formvalidation.js* then the JS file loads.

This shows the permissions on the *includes* and *javascript* folder:

```
user@server~site/httpdocs$ ls -la | grep includes
drwxr-xr-x  5 user www-data    4096 Jun 14 23:53 includes

user@server~site/httpdocs$ ls -la includes | grep .js
-rwxr-xr-x  1 user www-data 20974 Mar  2 22:33 formvalidation.js

user@server~site/httpdocs$ ls -la | grep javascript
drwxr-xr-x  3 user www-data    4096 Jun  3 11:03 javascript

user@server~site/httpdocs$ ls -la javascript | grep .js
-rwxrw-r-x  1 user www-data  7276 Mar  2 22:33 calendar.js
-rwxrw-r-x  1 user www-data 33321 Jun  3 11:03 cookieControl-5.1.min.js
-rwxrw-r-x  1 user www-data 15552 Mar  2 22:33 image_display.js
-rwxrw-r-x  1 user www-data 21130 Mar  2 22:33 popcalendar.js
-rwxrw-r-x  1 user www-data 67956 Mar  2 22:33 search.js
-rwxrw-r-x  1 user www-data   555 Mar 31 00:15 sell.js
-rwxrw-r-x  1 user www-data   318 Mar 31 00:15 sign_in.js
-rwxrw-r-x  1 user www-data   142 Mar 31 00:15 update.js
```

So the file is uploaded, it has the same permissions as other files in *includes*, and the *includes* and *javascript* folder both have the same permission.

There's no **.htaccess** file, and this works fine locally on my Dev server, it's only when I push live I get a problem.

**UPDATE**: I made a file, *test.js* and put it at the root. This could be viewed at *site.com/test.js*. I moved that, `mv test.js javascript/* and visiting *site.com/javascript/test.js* gives a 404

**UPDATE**: Checking */var/log/apache2/error.log* shows **File does not exist: /usr/share/javascript/search.js**

**UPDATE**: I've searched for *javscript* in my */etc/apache2* folder and found this:

```
user@site:/etc/apache2$ grep -iR javascript ./       
./mods-available/deflate.conf: AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript application/javascript  application/ecmascript    
./mods-enabled/deflate.conf: AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript application/javascript application/ecmascript
./conf.d/javascript-common.conf:Alias /javascript /usr/share/javascript/
./conf.d/javascript-common.conf:<Directory "/usr/share/javascript/">
```

Comment: What does the server log say? It should say where it's looking.

Comment: It's looking in */usr/share/javascript/search.js*

Comment: What would cause the files from */javascript/* to be searched for there? Would it be an .htaccess or vhost.conf setting somewhere? I've not set up anything like that intentionally, but this is old legacy code that I've taken over

Comment: Include the vhost config in your question.

Comment: There has to be some weird vhost config that's causing the issue. `/usr/share/` is common for some "installable" applications (webmin is one).

Comment: I've run `grep -iR javascript ./` in the */etc/apache2* folder, and found a few entries, I'll update the question

Comment: I generally use */js/* for my Javascript so this has never been a problem before. Am I safe to just delete those rules and restart apache?

Comment: It seems to be the config in conf.d/javascript-common.conf that's the problem. I'd move that file to e.g. /tmp for the moment and restart apache to see if that will a) fix it and b) not break anything else.

Comment: That solved it. Someone needs to propose an actual answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there was an alias in your `./conf.d/javascript-common.conf:` file that was causing Apache to look in the wrong place. As you noted, deleting those entries fixed the problem and Apache was happy.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me

```
sudo a2disconf javascript-common
```

This removes the `javascript-common.conf` from `conf-available` and `conf-enabled`.

Comment: This is perfectly worked for me. :) Thank you so much @sumit